# Splitting a variable name and melting the data with that split into separate columns in R

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I have some perfmon (Windows Performance Log Data) data I wish to parse.

Usually a set of column names look like the following:

```
> colnames(p)
[1] "Time"                                                         
[2] "\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length"      
[3] "\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length" 
[4] "\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length"
[5] "\\\\testdb1\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"             
[6] "\\\\testdb1\\System\\Processes"                               
[7] "\\\\testdb1\\System\\Processor Queue Length"
```

The way that I have inputted this data into R, is with:

```
p <- read.csv("r-perfmon.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Here is some example data

```
> head(p)
                     Time \\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length
1 04/15/2013 00:00:19.279                                             0.040037563
2 04/15/2013 00:00:34.279                                             0.009740260
3 04/15/2013 00:00:49.275                                             0.011009828
4 04/15/2013 00:01:04.284                                             0.006016244
5 04/15/2013 00:01:19.279                                             0.015125328
6 04/15/2013 00:01:34.275                                             0.002814141
  \\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length
1                                                  0.001421333
2                                                  0.000000000
3                                                  0.000206726
4                                                  0.000000000
5                                                  0.001894000
6                                                  0.000000000
  \\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length
1                                                   0.038616230
2                                                   0.009740260
3                                                   0.010803102
4                                                   0.006016244
5                                                   0.013231327
6                                                   0.002814141
  \\\\testdb1\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time \\\\testdb1\\System\\Processes
1                                        29.569339                             86
2                                        10.856994                             86
3                                         7.733924                             81
4                                         1.910202                             81
5                                         6.164864                             81
6                                         1.351883                             81
  \\\\testdb1\\System\\Processor Queue Length
1                                           0
2                                           0
3                                           0
4                                           0
5                                           0
6                                           0
```

What I want to be able parse the column names and then melt the data.

So if we take one column of data as an example

```
> example <- p[2]
> head(example)
  \\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length
1                                             0.040037563
2                                             0.009740260
3                                             0.011009828
4                                             0.006016244
5                                             0.015125328
6                                             0.002814141
```

I want it to look like this

```
Time, MachineName, Object, Counter, InstanceName, Value
04/15/2013 00:00:19.279, testdb1, PhysicalDisk, Avg. Disk Queue Length, 0 C:, 0.040037563
04/15/2013 00:00:34.279, testdb1, PhysicalDisk, Avg. Disk Queue Length, 0 C:, 0.009740260
04/15/2013 00:00:49.275, testdb1, PhysicalDisk, Avg. Disk Queue Length, 0 C:, 0.011009828
```

EDIT: As requested a dput of the head of my data

```
structure(list(`(PDH-CSV 4.0) (GMT Daylight Time)(-60)` = c("04/15/2013 00:00:19.279", 
"04/15/2013 00:00:34.279", "04/15/2013 00:00:49.275", "04/15/2013 00:01:04.284", 
"04/15/2013 00:01:19.279", "04/15/2013 00:01:34.275"), `\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length` = c(0.040037563, 
0.00974026, 0.011009828, 0.006016244, 0.015125328, 0.002814141
), `\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length` = c(0.001421333, 
0, 0.000206726, 0, 0.001894, 0), `\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length` = c(0.03861623, 
0.00974026, 0.010803102, 0.006016244, 0.013231327, 0.002814141
), `\\\\testdb1\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time` = c(29.56933862, 
10.85699395, 7.733924001, 1.910202013, 6.164864178, 1.351882837
), `\\\\testdb1\\System\\Processes` = c(86L, 86L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 
81L), `\\\\testdb1\\System\\Processor Queue Length` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("(PDH-CSV 4.0) (GMT Daylight Time)(-60)", 
"\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length", "\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length", 
"\\\\testdb1\\PhysicalDisk(0 C:)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length", 
"\\\\testdb1\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", "\\\\testdb1\\System\\Processes", 
"\\\\testdb1\\System\\Processor Queue Length"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: first reshape the data into long form using `reshape` in r and then use `strsplit` on the final column name. You also need to `dput` your data if you want other to reproduce your data.

Comment: I have it in long form `p <- melt(p, id=c("time")) `  but I am struggling with the strsplit

Comment: In wide format you can change each column one at a time ... but im unsure how the final dataset would look. But for your example ..`s <- strsplit(colnames(example), "\\\\|\\)|\\(")[[1]] ;  data.frame(t(s[nzchar(s)]), example[[1]])`

Comment: As requested I have included a dput of the head of my data

Comment: Gauss... thanks for the edit, but are you able to copy the `dput` from your question in to a fresh R session? It throws an error for me, due to the single backslash

Comment: edited with dput from fresh r session ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit difficult to know what your final data should look like, as if each column name is split by backslashes, or brackets, you get a different number of columns in the result depending on the input column.

So I have split each column into a seperate list element. If the data.frame from your `dput` is called `d`

```
# Look at second column - then all you need to do is tweak the names
s <- strsplit(colnames(d)[2], "\\\\|\\)|\\(")[[1]]
data.frame(time = d[[1]], t(s[nzchar(s)]), value=d[[2]])

                     time      X1           X2   X3                     X4       value
1 04/15/2013 00:00:19.279 testdb1 PhysicalDisk 0 C: Avg. Disk Queue Length 0.040037563
2 04/15/2013 00:00:34.279 testdb1 PhysicalDisk 0 C: Avg. Disk Queue Length 0.009740260
3 04/15/2013 00:00:49.275 testdb1 PhysicalDisk 0 C: Avg. Disk Queue Length 0.011009828
4 04/15/2013 00:01:04.284 testdb1 PhysicalDisk 0 C: Avg. Disk Queue Length 0.006016244
5 04/15/2013 00:01:19.279 testdb1 PhysicalDisk 0 C: Avg. Disk Queue Length 0.015125328
6 04/15/2013 00:01:34.275 testdb1 PhysicalDisk 0 C: Avg. Disk Queue Length 0.002814141
```

The `strsplit` splits each string at `\\` or `(` or `)` - note in R these need to be escaped with leading `\\`. This results in some empty strings which are removed by the `nzchar` function (returns FALSE if zero length)

```
# Apply it over all variables
lapply(seq_along(colnames(d))[-1], function(i) {
                 s <- strsplit(colnames(d)[[i]], "\\\\|\\)|\\(")[[1]]
                 data.frame(time = d[[1]], t(s[nzchar(s)]), value=d[[i]])
})
```

Again, you will need to rename the columns.

Comment: Thank you for this, a very good starting point. What seems to happen with this code is that I end up with a data frame with lots of columns time, x1,x2,time.1,x1.1,x2.1,time.2,x1.2 etc.  I was hoping that the data would have only  time, x1,x2 columns.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Gauss, im not quite sure what the expected output should look like, When I just did it over column two, it matches your expected outcome from your question. As the column names separate in to a different number of sections i am unsure how / if you want to combine them. Can you indicate how you want to combine the output from multiple columns please.

Comment: Maybe create three dataframes . one each for PhysicalDisk, Processor and System, and rbind the common columns together?